# Android XML code : how to place an image left of Textview?

Tags: android, xml

In my Android Application i have 2 textviews and 1 image to e displayed on the listview. While i used my imageview it is going to the new line..

I want one textview and imageview on the same line. Every time i place the imageview the whole alignment is changing ..

my XML code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"

            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:src="@drawable/album1" />


        <TextView
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
            android:id="@+id/textViewSongName"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewArtist"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="15dp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewDuration"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textSize="12dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: That is because you have put your `ImageView` in a vertical `LinearLayout` instead of horizontal one (like you did in your 3rd layout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this layout i have set weightSum property.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="1"> 
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.3">                
                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/icon"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
                    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="0.7">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewSongName"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="iconTextview"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                    android:textSize="22dp" />
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:weightSum="1"    
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewArtist"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                             android:text="textViewArtist"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />

                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="0dp"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:layout_weight="0.5">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textViewDuration"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                            android:text="textViewDuration"
                            android:textSize="12dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>
             </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

use **drawableleft** in your xml of textview

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/settingmenuright"
```

Answer (score 1):

The layout messes up because you have the `ImageView` and the `TextView` in a **vertical** `LinearLayout`. Do this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/album1" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
        android:id="@+id/textViewSongName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="22dp" />
     </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewArtist"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewDuration"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="12dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have moved the `ImageView` and `TextView` in another **horizontal** `LinearLayout`

Comment: its getting error on last closing of linear layout. Saying (Unexpected end of file)